# Why is wamp Apache not allowing APIs to access my www folder?

Tags: windows, apache, api, localhost, wamp

I have a piece of code where an external API needs to access my "www" folder for images. When I load the url, "http://localhost:8001/images/1.jpg" from the browser, it does show the image. But when I access it through the code it says, "connection refused". I have turned off the firewall as well. I also tried using the IP address instead of the "localhost".That doesn't work either. Please help.

Comment: Some code to see how you are accessing it from code would help. I expect it is a permissions issue.

Comment: Are you running this code on the PC running Apache or another PC in your network?

Comment: Im running this on the PC that runs on my machine. But I am passing this image to another Web API. So it gets accessed from some other machine outside my network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the domain name `localhost` has a special meaning. It always means this PC, or more accurately this network cards loopback address.

I cannot access your PC from here using the domain name localhost, as it will always be looped back to my PC.

If you want an external site to make a call to your PC then there are a number of things you will have to do.

- Buy yourself an domain name, you either buy a real one or use a Dynamic DNS service like dyndns.com or or noip.com

  Or you use your routers WAN ip address.
- Then you must amend the httpd.conf file so that Apache allows access
  from all ipaddress's
- Then you must Port Forward your Router so the the NAT firewall allows
  external accesses on port 80 to be forwarded to the internal PC
  running Apache, and only that PC.
- And possibly amend your software firewall on the Apache PC to allow access from external sources on port 80